# How to calculate the minute average?

Tags: average

I want to know how can I calculate the average minute of a time of a match. Each match is composed by two time, each time have a duration of 45 minutes, for a total of 90 minutes. 
I have these data available:

```
Position: 1  
Played matches: 27  
Wins: 18    
Draws: 4    
Losses: 5   
Goal scored: 50 
Goal against    : 22    
Points: 58
Clean sheets: 12    
Avg. goals scored p/m: 1.85 
Avg. goals conceded p/m:    0.81    
Avg. time 1st goal scored: 36m  
Avg. time 1st goal conced.: 30m 
Failed to score: 3  
Biggest victory: 4 - 0  
Biggest defeat: 0 - 2
```

the data that I'm interested to calculate is:

- Avg. time 1st goal scored: 36m
- Avg. time 1st goal conced: 30m

I tried to get these result doing 90  / 1.85 = 49 but is of course wrong, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot calculate the average time until the first goal without further assumptions or better data.

Just imagine all goals were scored within the first/last minute of the match. This would not have any effect on the data you provided (except the "Avg. time 1st goal scored" of course, but if I get you right you want to calculate this from the rest of the data).

Comment: So for calculate this data I need the minute of each goal scored or conceded of the team? Suppose I have also all this data for the first time, how the formula can be configured?

Comment: Yes, you need those. If you have them, isolate the first goals and simply take the average minute.